# Fit function for magnetization (ab plane) for $\mathrm{YBa_2Cu_3O_{6.5}}$ monocrystal, where does it come from?

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, superconductivity, crystals, magnetic-moment

So I've got this graph from a source I was told to check.
It's about the measurement of magnetization in a $\mathrm{YBa_2Cu_3O_{6.5}}$ monocrystal along the $ab$ axis.
The only equation in the whole article that concerns magnetization (so that we have some sort of y(x) = ax^n...) is the magnetization along the c axis:
\begin{equation}
M_c^{FL}= - \frac{\pi k_BTH}{3\Phi_0^2} \frac{\xi_{ab}^2}{s\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{2\xi_{ab}}{\gamma s} \right)^2}} \;\; ,
\end{equation}
where $\gamma$ is anisotropy, $\xi_{ab}(T) = \xi_{ab}/\epsilon$ and $\xi_{c}(T) = \xi_{c}/\epsilon$, $\epsilon=\ln (T/T_c)$ temperature dependent coherence values in $ab$ lines and $c$ axis. Value $s = 1.17$ nm is
the distance between parallel CuO$_2$ lines, $\Phi_0$ is the magnetic flux quanta and $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant.

[image: Magnetization-temperature of YBCO in ab plane]

and the fitting function is $$y = a+\frac{b}{1+\exp[-(x-T_c)/c]}$$

Where does this curve come from?
I can't for the life of me figure it out. Even when I've tried to simplify the above expression to get the fit function, I've reached a dead end. No way I can simplify the ln(x/T$_c$) like that.
I've gone through Tinkham's Superconductivity and I still couldn't figure it out. The only sane thing that comes to my mind is that this is either a computer fit, but even if it is, it's basis needs to be in physics because the units of $c$ and $T_c$ are Kelvin, or that I'm missing something so simple that it makes me look stupid.
Thanks in advance.